# static uitableviewcells with custom classes not showing content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I'm working with Xcode 6.1.1, and I have a table view controller with static cells having 4 sections.

- Section 0: contains two rows, each with 2 labels
- Section 1: contains 7 image views
- Section 2: contains 1 row with 1 label
- Section 3: contains a variable number or rows each containing 2 image
  views

I want to load all cells in the table view controller with data.

I gave each different row a reuse identifier (5 reuse identifiers in total), and I also created a class for each of the different kind of cells (5 classes)

I created outlets in the classes, and linked them in the storyboard each to its label/image view.

However I don't know how to proceed next.

If I implement the table view data source functions, I'm getting the correct number of cells, however they are all blank.

Here's how I'm creating the cells:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell1";
        MyTableViewCell1 *cell = (MyTableViewCell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[MyTableViewCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
    } else {
        //create other cells here
    }
    cell.label1.text=@"testing 123";
    return cell;
}
```

However, I'm always getting cells with default style (my labels or image views are not appearing)

What am I missing?? What code should I write in the custom table view cell classes?

EDIT: After gavin's suggestion, I modified the delegate function to use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath

I also added: [self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell1 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell1"] to my viewdidload method.

Here's my final code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell1 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell1"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 3 ) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        // make dynamic row's cell
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell1";
        MyTableViewCell1 *cell = (MyTableViewCell1*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [cell configureCellWithValues:@"17" andV2:@"13"];
        return cell;
    } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 3) {
        MyTableViewCell1 *c = (MyTableViewCell1 *) cell;
        NSLog(@"willdisplay cell with values %@, %@",c.i1, c.i2);
        [c.image1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2"]];
    }
}
```

And here's my custom cell's class:

```
@implementation MyTableViewCell1

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void) configureCellWithValues: (NSString*) v1 andV2:(NSString*) v2 {
    self.i1=v1;
    self.i2=v2;
    self.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:v1];
    self.image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:v2];
}

@end
```

The cells in section 3 are still not showing the images (not even the imageviews)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we can't generate custom static cells and try to access their outlets and change them (because their static) please correct me if i'm wrong because I couldn't access them at all.

I've solved my Problem by changing the TableView Type to Dynamic Cells, i didn't put any prototype cells in the tableview and I have created 3 different Cell Classes (with their nibs)

I have registered the nib files with the tableview by adding this to the viewdidload method:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCellType1" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellType1"];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCellType2" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellType2"];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCellType3" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellType3"];
```

then i fully customized my tableview methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 2;
            break;
        case 1:
            return 1;
        case 2:
            return [self.myarray count];
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0: {
            MyCellType1 *cell = (MyCellType1 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellType1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            //this section always has 2 rows
            if (indexPath.row==0) {
                cell.lblTitle.text = @"ID";
                cell.lblValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",1277];
            } else {
                cell.lblTitle.text = @"Date";
                cell.lblValue.text = @"02/03/2015";
            }
            return cell;
        }
            break;
        case 1: {
                MyCellType2 *cell = (MyCellType2 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellType2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
                cell.image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3"];
                cell.image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4"];
                return cell;
        }
        case 2: {
            MyCellType3 *cell = (MyCellType3 *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellType3" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.lblName.text = @"New Row";
            return cell;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you're using the *old* method of `tableView` reusable cell dequeueing - the new function accepts an `indexPath` as well as the cell identifier; it also now guarantees to return a cell (so no need for a nil check).

Here's your delegate function cleaned up:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell1";
        MyTableViewCell1 *cell = (MyTableViewCell1*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        //create other cells here
    }
    cell.label1.text=@"testing 123";
    return cell;
}
```

Another tip would be to encapsulate your setting of the label values into each individual cell subclass, e.g. add a method called `configure` to `MyTableViewCell1` that sets the label values to what you want displayed.

Comment: i changed the code and now i'm getting a crash: *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]... and after searching the net I found out that I need to use either registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: before being able to use this selector. and because I don't have a nib file, I used the following code in my viewdidload: [self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell1 class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell1"]; the crash is gone but the cell is still empty